# How to use android pay api with nfc?

Tags: android, android-pay

I am trying to implement **"Tap and Pay(for payment transaction)"** with **NFC** and **Android Pay API**.

I did not find any tutorials or examples regarding this.

I looked at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html) but did not get it.

The above documentation talks about communicating with **NFC** using **Host-based Card Emulation**  (I might be wrong)

How can this be achieved? Are there other APIs or do I have to integrate a **payment protocol** with a **Host-based Card Emulation** Service?

```
public class MyHostApduService extends HostApduService {
    @Override
    public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] apdu, Bundle extras) {

       //Implement PAYMENT protocol here
    }
    @Override
    public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I've understood, Android Pay API is about integrating payment methods into your APP (i.e. to pay for a pizza order within your app), not for integrating with NFC terminals. This is handled by Android Pay-App exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Comment from [icyerasor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314089/icyerasor) is completely right. If you want to pay for something with Android pay and NFC, you should use Android Pay application. You can't implement custom payment application because of security issues (for example, google [doesn't allow Android pay on rooted devices](http://www.howtogeek.com/241012/safetynet-explained-why-android-pay-and-other-apps-dont-work-on-rooted-devices/) or on devices with custom screen locks).

As for Android Pay API - it is designed to pay without any NFC terminal - only from your application. You can see [typical payment flows here](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/payment-flows) - those can't include any NFC contacts.

If you wonder, what is NFC card emulation designed for - it can be used for person identification instead of cards, for storing bus tickets and etc. I think that it is possible to make a custom payment system - but it will require creating custom bank processing and NFC terminals (card readers) at least (I repeat once again that you can't use Android Pay). That's almost impossible for a little company which business isn't in this field (very expensive, requires lots of licensing work and time). And even after it, your application will be banned in google play.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other commenters have noted.

> As for Android Pay API - it is designed to pay without any NFC terminal ...
>
> *answered Aug 16 at 11:42*
>   [Jehy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727132/jehy)

However, you may want to look into something like [Square](https://squareup.com/contactless-chip-reader), they make NFC readers that accept Android Pay. They cost about $50.00, which I personally feel is inexpensive for a small business or individual.

You should also look at their [APIs](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/) and in particular

> **In-person commerce**. Custom iOS and Android point-of-sale apps can use the Square Register API to process payments securely with Square hardware.

Armed with the $50 NFC reader and a custom built point-of-sale app you can in a round about way achieve a reasonable solution. Though your users **will be** using Android Pay or Apple Pay for contact-less payments(no point reinventing the wheel).

#### Disclaimer

As of the time of this answer Square APIs are not offered everywhere.

> **Important:** Square APIs are currently available only in the United States and Canada. We are working to make them available in additional countries soon.